# In a page layout template, how do I show the value of a "Multiple lines of text" field so that it properly displays rich-text HTML formatting?

Tags: page-layout

I am creating Page Layout templates in a text editor for a Sharepoint 2013 site. My content type has a *Multiple lines of text* field with *Enhanced rich text* set as an option.

In my Page Template the input control is coded like this:

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-panel-home">
   <SharePointWebControls:RichTextField FieldName="Herotext" runat="server" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Farther down the page I render the field value like this:

```
<SharePoint:FieldValue runat="server" FieldName="Herotext" />
```

This partially works in that the field is rendered, but it is displaying the HTML formatting tags as text. Meaning the output looks like this:

`<strong>Welcome</strong> this is my <em>hero text</em>!`

instead of this

**Welcome** this is my *hero text*

**What is the proper way to insert my rich text field value into my page template to avoid seeing HTML tags in the output?**